# Vim: How to create a custom compound command with no timeout?

Tags: vim, binding, timeout, mapping, command

In Vim there are certain built-in compound commands which have no timeout, for example: `g` waits forever for the next keystroke. I would like to create my custom compound binding to behave like that. But, preferably, other bindings shouldn't be affected (I imply the possibility of using `set notimeout` setting here). If that's not possible to achieve for a particular binding then I guess I have to fall back to `set notimeout` setting. So are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are fine with not working `showcmd` and cursor positioned in bottom-right corner while pending for next character then use `getchar()`:

```
nnoremap <Plug>PluginAction-a do-something-here-for-key-a
function s:Getchar()
    let char=getchar()
    if type(char)==type(0)
        return nr2char(char)
    endif
    return char
endfunction
nmap <expr> \g "<Plug>PluginAction-".<SID>Getchar()
```

.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at Vim's programming. Could you explain `nnoremap <Plug>PluginAction-a do-something-here-for-key-a` and `nmap <expr> \g "<Plug>PluginAction-".<SID>Getchar()`. Just to be more specific, for example I want `l` to do nothing else, but wait for the next stroke forever. So `li`, `lo` would do something. Could you update your answer so that I could see how it should look like exactly for my case. Thank you.

Comment: @Haroogan Replace `\g` with `l` in `nmap`. Add `nnoremap <Plug>PluginAction-i …` and `nnoremap <Plug>PluginAction-o …` (for `li` and `lo` respectively). See `:h :map-expression` and `:h :map`, there is no magic here.

Answer (score 2):

As long as there is no overlap with built-in commands, you can create a mapping to the first key of your compound mapping only, and consume all subsequent keys of your compound mapping via `getchar()` (which waits indefinitely for the key), then dispatches to the corresponding handler based on the full sequence of entered keys.

This certainly isn't as comfortable as direct mappings, but should do the trick. Though I would really think hard whether a good value for `'timeoutlen'` doesn't already solve your problem; at least I have never perceived this as a problem.